# how to set a variable in options.js chrome.storage.sync and call it in background.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

This extension is supposed to allow users to select a site that they wish to search quickly using a keyword in the **omnibox**.

Here is my `options.html`. This file should give users the ability to pick a website preference and save it to `chrome.storage.sync`. I set a default to search google:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Search Options</title></head>
<body>

Search:
<select id="url">
    <option value="https://google.com/search?q=">Site1</option>
    <option value="url#2.com?search=">
    Site2
    </option>
</select>

<div id="status"></div>
<button id="save">Save</button>

<script src="options.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

my options.js. This file is supposed to contain functions that save and restore options:

```
// Saves options to chrome.storage
function save_options() {
  var url = document.getElementById('url').value;
  chrome.storage.sync.set({prefSite: url}, function() {
    // Update status to let user know options were saved.
    var status = document.getElementById('status');
    status.textContent = 'Options saved.';
    setTimeout(function() {
          status.textContent = '';
    }, 750);
  });
}

// Restores select box and checkbox state using the preferences
// stored in chrome.storage.
function restore_options() {
  // Use default site: Google
  chrome.storage.sync.get({prefSite: 'https://google.com/search?q='}, function(items) {
    document.getElementById('url').value = items.prefSite;
  });
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', restore_options);
document.getElementById('save').addEventListener('click',
    save_options);
```

and my `background.js`. In this file I allow the user to search their selected webpage from the **omnibox** using a keyword:

```
function resetDefaultSuggestion() {
  chrome.omnibox.setDefaultSuggestion({
    description: 'Search for: %s'
  });
}

resetDefaultSuggestion();

chrome.omnibox.onInputCancelled.addListener(function() {
  resetDefaultSuggestion();
});


chrome.omnibox.onInputEntered.addListener(function(text) {
  var prefSite = chrome.storage.sync.get("prefSite", function (obj) {
    console.log(obj);
  });
  var SearchURL = prefSite + text;
  chrome.tabs.create({url: SearchURL });
});
```

When I try to search I see [this page](http://screencast.com/t/I7WlPYPMf). Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: `chrome.storage.sync.get` has no returned value, you can't assign it to `prefSite`, see duplicated link for how to retrieve returned data from aynnchronous call.